# are there any alternates for System.Diagnostics.process class in c# (as it is unavailable for windows 8 store apps)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, command-prompt, windows-store-apps

I want to open up some tasks by using command prompt commands in my windows 8 store app (metro app ) .if it is a desktop app , then i will go for process class in system namespace. now it  seems that it is unavailable for windows 8 store apps .so i am in need of a class or a function that will run command prompt commands in windows 8 store apps .

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible. You are sandboxed when you make a Windows 8 application. You cannot launch another application from within your app.

Comment: i am trying to launch a .vbs file in my project . is it possible to launch it by any other method ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not with a Windows Store application.